# Choosing a team with 17 men and 22 women?

Tags: combinatorics

I have attempted the question below, but would appreciate a review of my work and any help you can give me.

In a class of 39 students, there are 17 men and 22 women.

1. How many ways are there to choose 3 equal teams?

$13 \choose 3$^3
Is this correct since each of the teams are independent of one another?

2. What are the possible ways to choose teams with a gender distribution as uniform as possible? (3 ways)

Team 1 (7 women, 6 men) Team 2 (7 women, 6 men) Team 3 (8 women, 5 men)

Team 1 (7 women, 6 men) Team 2 (7 women, 5 men) Team 3 (8 women, 6 men)

Team 1 (7 women, 5 men) Team 2 (7 women, 6 men) Team 3 (8 women, 6 men)

3. How many ways are there to choose the students for each of the possibilities

$7 \choose 6$$7 \choose 6$$7 \choose 5$$7 \choose 6$$7 \choose 5$$7 \choose 6$$8 \choose 5$$8 \choose 6$$8 \choose 6$
I just multiplied the possibilities, but I don't think this is correct.

4. What is the total number of ways to choose teams that have the most uniform gender distribution?

Is this question different from 3? How do I approach it?

Comment: Your answer to (1) is wrong. I suggest you work out how many ways there are to choose three equal size teams when there are $6$ students in total: choose the first team. Then the second. Do you have any choice for the third? Does it matter which order you chose the teams in? That should tell you why your formula is wrong and how to proceed.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for the response. Would $39 \choose 13$*$26 \choose 13$*$13 \choose 13$ be correct?

Comment: Almost. Do you see why you should now divide by $3!$? (And the last factor in your expression is, of course, $1$ and can be omitted, though including it shows your thinking.) Finally: you have really asked four questions. One per posting is the norm here. Please edit to remove the last ones. Repost them separately, showing your work so far in each case.

Comment: Think of 1 as the number of ways of selecting 13 A, 13 B and 13 C. The result turns out to be $$\frac{39!}{13!13!13!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to 1 in the comment is close, but you are expected to recognize that if you choose team $A$ first and team $B$ second, leaving team $C$, that is the same as choosing $C$ first, $A$ second, and $B$ third.  You don't care what order the teams are chosen.

I think your answer to 2 is the intended one, but am not sure.  I don't know what definition of "as uniform as possible" they are using.

For 3 you are supposed to do each of the possibilities separately.  I would just add the three results for 4, but not be confident that is what is being asked.